# Output dates based on an array

Tags: scheduled-tasks, autohotkey, associative-array

Need Help. I have an associative array which has the days of the week. I know very little about arrays. Each day has a 1 or 0 in the array below. I am trying to output dates and use them to generate tasks. I'm sure can this be done easily, but I lack the experience.

1. I want to output only dates which have 1's as shown in the array below.
2. The first task is due in 4 days.
3. I need to view dates up to 3 days ahead, so if today is Tuesday, and start is on Friday, then the Friday task date won't appear until Wednesday.

```
Today := A_now       
WeekDays_Array := {Sun: 0, Mon: 0, Tue: 1, Wed: 0, Thu: 1, Fri: 1, Sat: 0}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about the dates. #2 mentions a task being due in 4 days, but then #4 mentions 14 days from Friday (which is still a Friday). Would you please flesh out your instructions a bit more?

Comment: I took the last part out. Basically I just need to wait a period of time before regenerating the same date tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is most of it. The suggestion to use the array above made the most sense.

The script uses Wkday (which is A_Now) as the start day but I think that can be changed by substituting it for a specific start day

```
PastDue := []
DueBy := []
;~ Weekday_Array := {Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 1, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 1, Friday: 1, Saturday: 0}
Weekday_Array := [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]            ;Represents Sun-Saturday

AssignTask:
FormatTime, WkDay, MyTime, WDay
For i, value in Weekday_Array{
DueDate =
        if (i > WkDay && Value = 1){
            x++
            DueDate += (x), days
            FormatTime, DueDate, % DueDate, MM/dd/yy
            DueBy.InsertAt(i,DueDate)
        }       
        if (i = WkDay && Value = 1){
            FormatTime, DueDate, % A_Now, MM/dd/yy
            DueBy.InsertAt(i,DueDate)
        }       
        if (i < WkDay && Value = 1){
            y--
            Pastdate =
            PastDate += (y) , days
            NewDate := PastDate
            NewDate += 7, days
            FormatTime, PastDate, % PastDate, MM/dd/yy
            FormatTime, NewDate, % NewDate, MM/dd/yy
            PastDue.InsertAt(i,PastDate)
            DueBy.insertAt(i,NewDate)
        }
}

For i, PastDue in PastDue
    PastDueDates .= PastDue "`n"
Sort, PastDueDates
PastDueDates := "Past due dates so far this week `n`n" PastDueDates
MsgBox, 0x1000,, % PastDueDates

For i, DueDate in DueBy
    DueDates .= DueDate "`n"
Sort, DueDates
DueDates := "All upcoming due dates based criteria `n`n" DueDates
MsgBox, 0x1000,, % DueDates
sort, DueDates

FormatTime, xDay1, % A_Now, MM/dd/yy
xDay2 += 1, days
FormatTime, xDay2, % xDay2, MM/dd/yy
xDay3 += 2, days    
FormatTime, xDay3, % xDay3, MM/dd/yy


For i, DueDate in DueBy{
    if (DueDate = xDay1 || DueDate = xDay2 || DueDate = xDay3)
        XDays .= DueDate "`n"
}
xDays := "Only view the next 3 days from today `n`n" xDays
MsgBox, 0x1000,, % xDays
;~ return

*esc::
ExitApp
return
```